# Install Rmosek under 3.4.4 using macOS

Tags: r, installation, package

I'd like to install the packages Rmosek with R 3.4.4 version. 
I have this problem:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rmosek’ ...
** package ‘Rmosek’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Configuring for a UNIX-alike platform (sub-architecture: "")
Found package 'Matrix' version 1.2.14
*** No variable 'PKG_MOSEKHOME' in environment - see configure-vars (configure.vars) argument ***
*** No variable 'PKG_MOSEKHOME' in ./src/setup/Localsys.txt file ***
*** Shell command 'mosek' was not recognized - please validate your installation of MOSEK ***
***   >> PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin  ***
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmosek’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rmosek’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rmosek’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/42/p9yl3yln6zn8dq_3zdd496kr0000gn/T/RtmpBe0vs2/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: If you want to do manual installation, this variable should point to where you keep your Mosek download. Alternative options are described in https://docs.mosek.com/8.1/rmosek/install-interface.html#id1

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by this post:  https://gist.github.com/mikelove/67ea44d5be5a053e599257fe357483dc#file-rmosek-L19

1) Download mosek from here:
https://www.mosek.com/downloads/
(I downloaded this to my ~/bin)

cd ~/bin
tar -xvf mosektoolslinux64x86.tar.bz2

2) Add this to your ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin/mosek/8/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin

3) Get academic license:
https://www.mosek.com/products/academic-licenses/
Check email, put licsense file in ~/mosek

4) Install:

export PKG_MOSEKHOME=/home/username/bin/mosek/8/tools/platform/linux64x86
export PKG_MOSEKLIB=mosek64

Then in R:
install.packages("Rmosek", type="source", INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch", repos="http://download.mosek.com/R/8")